# How to grant application access to Office365 with OAuth?

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, oauth, office365

I tried to let the user browse to a webpage where he has to decide if my application gets access to his files on OneDrive for Business.

I did this with the following code and the use of [this website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx#10537267):

```
private string _authorizationEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/[code]/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0/";
private string _tokenEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/";
private string _clientId = "[Client Id]";
private string _resource = "https%3A%2F%2F[company]-my.sharepoint.com%2F"; 
private string _redirectURI = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nu.nl%2F";
private string _state = "5gdfd60b-8447-4536-b23f-fcb658e19458"; 
private string _authorizationCode = "";

private TokenInformation _tokenInformation = new TokenInformation();
private AuthorizationInformation _authorizationInformation = new AuthorizationInformation();

private void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(GetAuthorizationUrl());
}

private string GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    // Create a request for an authorization code.
    string url = string.Format("{0}common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&resource={3}&state={4}",
            _authorizationEndpoint,
            _clientId,
            _redirectURI,
            _resource,
            _state);
    return url; //"https://login.windows.net/[code]/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[Client Id]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nu.nl%2F&resource=https:%2f%2foutlook.office365.com%2f&state=5gdfd60b-8447-4536-b23f-fcb658e19458"
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    txtUrl.Text = e.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("code=") && e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("state"))
    {
        var splited = e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split(new char[] { '=', '&' });
        _authorizationInformation.Code = splited[1];
        _authorizationInformation.SessionState = splited[3];

        if (_authorizationInformation.SessionState.Equals(_state)) // Needs to change every request in order to avoid CSRF
        {
            GetTokenInformation(_authorizationInformation);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cross-site request forgery", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

private string GetAdminPermissionUrl()
{
    return string.Format("{0}common/oauth2/authorize?&response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&resource={3}&state={4}&prompt=admin_consent",
            _authorizationEndpoint,
            _clientId,
            _redirectURI,
            _resource,
            _state
        );
}

private TokenInformation GetTokenInformation(AuthorizationInformation authInformation)
{
    try
    {
        var response = Post(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_tokenEndpoint + "common/oauth2/token/"), new NameValueCollection(){ 
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "code", authInformation.Code },
            { "redirect_uri", _redirectURI },
            { "client_id", _clientId },
            //{ "client_secret", "" }, According to the website I mentioned I need to have a clientsecret, but this is a nativa application so I dont have one
        });

        Stream responseStream = new MemoryStream(response);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            _tokenInformation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenInformation>(json);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error" + exception.HResult.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return null;
}


public byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
{
    byte[] response = null;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
    }
    return response;
}
```

**- You can assume that I have used the correct credentials.**

When the user signs in and grants access. 
I get a code returned to trade for an accesstoken and a refreshtoken, according to the website I mentioned earlier.

Now there is a problem, I don't have a client_secret (in Azure Active Directory), because I develop a native app I guess.

The GetTokenInformation method does not work right now.
How do I obtain an accesstoken and refresh token correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide a "client_secret" parameter if you configured your application as a native application in the Azure Management Portal.

However, you *do* need to provide a "resource" parameter in your POST to the token authorization end point. this is a string that refers to the Office 365 resource you wish to obtain the access/refresh tokens for. This would be the same resource string that you already used in the initial authentication request url. *(edit: I think it's not even necessary to add the resource parameter to the initial authentication request - it works without it in my tests.  But it is certainly necessary when POSTing to the authorization endpoint to obtain the tokens)*

Lastly, you should also make sure that your native app has the right permissions settings in the Azure Management Portal. More specifically, when not already the case, you'll need to add the "Office 365 Sharepoint Online" app to the section 'Permissions To Other Applications' and mark the necessary detailed permissions for that application as checked.

Answer (score 0):

v2.0 Protocols - OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2#6-create-connections`

```
private static string redirectDomain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"];
        private string state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        private static string client_id = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O365ClientId"];
        private static string client_secret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O365ClientSecret"];
 public ActionResult IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id="+client_id+"&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Controllers/o365login/callback&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=" + state;
            return  Redirect(url);
        }
    public async void Callback(string code,string state)
        {
            var o365UserInfo = await getO365UserInfo(code);
            if(o365UserInfo != null)
            {
                O365user o365User =   GetEmailFromIdToken(o365UserInfo.access_token);
                if (o365User != null)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    private async Task<O365UserInfo> getO365UserInfo(string code)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://localhost/Controllers/o365login/callback"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret));
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData))
                    {
                        content.Headers.Clear();
                        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content };
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
                        O365UserInfo o365UserInfo= await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<O365UserInfo>();
                        return o365UserInfo;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
class O365UserInfo
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public int expires_in { get; set; }
            public string expires_on { get; set; }
            public string resource { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public string id_token { get; set; }
        }
        class O365user
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string upn { get; set; }
        }
```

`